# QTableWidget: dragging and selecting outside the QTableWidgetItem area

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget and I have scrolling enabled (click mouse and drag without releasing so the items can be selected). However, the dragging (and item selection) stops if I move my mouse outside the area where the QTableWidgetItems are. Is there an easy way to fix this?

In the picture below I show where dragging stops

[image]

I am using PyQt5

code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys

class Table(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(9)
        self.setRowCount(1)
        for r in range(1):
            for i in range(9):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(i)
                self.setItem(r, i, item)

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = QWidget()
   window.setGeometry(200,200,1200,400)
   tw = Table(window)
   twLayout = QVBoxLayout()
   twLayout.addWidget(tw)
   window.setLayout(twLayout)

   window.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc hey, sorry that I am not providing a minimal example at the moment, it will take time to rewrite the current code, because it is very lengthy. What I mean, is when I press on one QTableWidgetItem and drag my mouse, it selects all the items above which my mouse is, but only if my mouse is hovering over the items, not outside of that area. Usually in any dragging the items get selected if the mouse x coordinates correlate with the items x coordinates (in horizontal dragging), but not in this case

Comment: @eyllanesc here is the code. If you press on an item and then without releasing your mouse drag it above the area where the items are, they do not get selected, even if x coordinates match (even if the mouse hovers above headers)

Comment: @eyllanesc yep. You can copy paste it and run yourself...

Comment: @eyllanesc see that's the thing, I do not need the items to be dragged. I just need them to be selected while I drag the mouse, EVEN if the mouse is not hovering right above the item which I want to be selected. Sorry if I am unclear

Comment: @eyllanesc I have never once mentioned drag AND drop, you decided that I did. Mouse is draggable by the way. Please only comment with a solution, I have now edited everything that there is no way to be confused. The code is also easily testable. Also you are not obligated to keep commenting on this specific post.